# Bezier curve polynomial coefficients

Tags: polynomials, bezier-curve

How can I calculate coefficients for Bezier polynomial? I can do this manually on the paper, but I need to plug this into program, where degree of polynomial can be higher than 3 (more than 4 control points). Is there some universal scheme, like eg. Pascal triangle, to evaluate coefficients ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. Take a look at [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Polynomial_form) on the Wikipedia page of the topic. The coefficients can be calculated as follows:

$$\mathbf C_j=\frac{n!}{(n-j)!}\sum_{i=0}^j\frac{(-1)^{i+j}\mathbf P_i}{i!(j-i)!}$$

Here $n$ is the order of the curve, $\mathbf C_j$ is the coefficient of the $j$-th power term in the polynomial and $\mathbf P_i$ is the $i$-th control point. The page warns of the numeric instability of the direct formula for high order curves and points to [De Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm), if this is a problem.

Note that you can optimize some of the calculations here. For example, rather than computing the factorials $n!$ and $(n-j)!$ and taking their ratio, you can simply take the product of the integers $(n-j+1), (n-j+2),\dots,n$. This will also probably be more accurate.

Comment: Great, I missed that on wiki.. I only quite dont understand your optimize note. Plus, how can it be more accurate, if I compute factorial in integers (assume, that there is no overflow)?

Comment: @Martin: I mean the ratio $n!\over(n-j)!$. Calculating $n!$ and $(n-j)!$ separately is more computationally expensive than just the product $\prod_{i=n-j+1}^ni$. And about the accuracy issue, you may be right. I just assumed that dividing could cause some problems.

Comment: @Martin: Let me know if my explanation made sense to you. I'll check back in an hour or two.